# open url in new window from xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I had xml file which have some data .and I had navigation url tage this url to new website I tried to open this url in new window not in same window but I couldnot please any one help me.

```
<xml file>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Advertisements>
  <Ad>
    <ImageUrl>images/Ad_1.jpg</ImageUrl>
    <NavigateUrl>http://toshiba.elarabygroup.com/Category.aspx?cid=25</NavigateUrl>
    <AlternateText></AlternateText>
    <Keyword></Keyword>
    <Impressions>80</Impressions>
    <Caption></Caption>

  </Ad>
</Advertisements>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<a href=''>` with `AdRotator` control.